# php preg_replace pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace, pattern-matching

I need a hand on my `preg_replace` pattern:

I want to replace the texts between brackets `[]` but also inside brackets and not only until the first one `[.[.].....]` and the same pattern but to replace only numbers inside those brackets.

any idea?

Comment: can you give an example? (Source and expected Result) but from what i guess your Case doesn't sound "regular" and by definition may not be matchable by regular expressions

Comment: Can you try to explain what you want a little more detailed, perhaps posting some sample input data along with expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
$re = '#\[(?:.*?(?0))*.*?\]#'
```

This will match a [...] pair, which may itself contain one or more [...] pairs, with any characters between them. This is done by using recursion in the pattern (the `(?0)` *calls* the pattern again).

```
preg_match($re, '[.[.]....]', $m);
print_r($m);

// Output:
// Array
// (
//    [0] => [.[.]....]
// )
```